# Mysterious VBIDE reference in C# project broken

Tags: c#, reference, com

I created a software program ages ago, and have just opened up the project and when I try to compile, it throws up two errors in reference to VBIDE:

> Warning   2   Cannot find wrapper assembly for type library "VBIDE". Verify that (1) the COM component is registered correctly and (2) your target platform is the same as the bitness of the COM component. For example, if the COM component is 32-bit, your target platform must not be 64-bit.    SonicPhoto

...and:

> Warning   3   The referenced component 'VBIDE' could not be found.

The thing is - I don't ever remember adding this reference as my project is a sound orientated program and VBIDE is "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3" which has nothing to do with C#, let alone my program. If I remove the reference, the solution compiles and seems to run perfectly. I presume I am completely safe to remove it if it runs?

Perhaps I added this reference by mistake? Just to also say, I have older archived of my software, and the reference is there too, and none of the those compile either, when I know for a fact that at least one of the older copies of my software would have compiled. I also have a copy on another computer, and the reference is there too, but the reference isn't broken, so the project compiles and runs.

Comment: I am pretty sure that is part of adding some references like Excel object library (esp with "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3" )

Answer (score 19):

On Solution Explorer, 
Click Show all Files, 
Click References, 
Select VBIDE,
RightClick it and Remove it.

Comment: Not sure if you're joking or not ;-).

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As [WelcomeOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31039134/mysterious-vbide-reference-in-c-sharp-project-broken#comment50102865_31039134) suggested this solved it for me:

```
Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications  ->  Menu  ->  Extras  ->  Links
-> [x]  Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is necroing a post but I had the same issue and solved it.

I have visual studio code I am trying to compile/build from source and did not have this VBIDE reference. I also needed RSlinx installed for an OPCautomation reference (its an industrial driver program for Rockwell automation) and Microsoft office since the program is creating an excel file.

Any who, long story short after I installed office 365 visual studio suddenly had the Vbide reference which it could not locate before. Deleting the Vbide reference also allowed it to compile so I would back up the program and try that first.

Cheers

Answer (score -1):

Ran into the same problem.
Installed Office 2007 and the problem was fixed